# Anime where the MC has a ring of light on his chest and monsters can look like people

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched an anime a couple years ago on Netflix where the MC had a ring of light on his chest or maybe it was on his head? This ring of light when exposed revealed monsters or demons that were nearby.

He turns into a hero (?) maybe, it's a suit of armor but I'm pretty sure he transforms into a robot or something.

I remember one part of the anime where his girlfriend turns out to be one of the monsters planted by the main protagonist to spy on him and when she transforms she's crying or just in distress and yelling at him to not look at her.

I saw *Ultraman* pop up on Netflix and that sort of looked like it but that wasn't it.

Comment: "Ring of light on his chest, turns into a robot" just screams Iron Man. I believe there's an Iron Man anime, but I dunno if it's on Netflix.

Comment: There is indeed an Iron Man anime, but it doesn't match any of the other points you mentioned.

Comment: Wouldnt this be better suited for https://anime.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @GamerGypps Id questions are off topic on Anime SE.

Comment: @Kitkat Oh right, that seems absurdly strange in my opnion but fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a lot like one of the three OVAs based on the manga *[Bio-Booster Armor Guyver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bio_Booster_Armor_Guyver)*, but it’s been a long time since I’ve seen the 1989 series and I haven’t seen the other two.

The Guyver armour is a bio-tech suit of alien origin that appears when called by its host.

The “ring of light on his chest” could be the sphere that is actually in his head - which I believe is a weapon and is called the Control Medal.

He also has a powerful cannon that is exposed by him opening his chest, so you could be mixing up memories here.

[image]

I vaguely recall the “girlfriend being a monster” twist, but the Wikipedia page is thin on specific plot details.